# Does albumentations normalize mask?

Tags: pytorch, albumentations

When I pass an `image` and a `mask` to `albumentations.Normalize(mean, std)`.

How would I go about incorporating this?
Should I just add it manually in dataset?

Grateful for any tips you have!

Comment: Have you come up with any ideas?

Comment: @yakhyo yes, as mentioned, I just run it seperately, once for the images and once for the masks outside of the other transforms

Answer (score 2):

Edited:

Normalization works for three-channel images. If your mask image is grayscale image then probably you need to **stack**(`image= np.stack((img,)*3, axis=-1)`)
it and make three channel image then apply albumentations's Normalization function. Official function for `A.Normalize()` is as following which deals with **RGB** images:

```py
def normalize(img, mean, std, max_pixel_value=255.0):
    mean = np.array(mean, dtype=np.float32)
    mean *= max_pixel_value

    std = np.array(std, dtype=np.float32)
    std *= max_pixel_value

    denominator = np.reciprocal(std, dtype=np.float32)

    img = img.astype(np.float32)
    img -= mean
    img *= denominator
    return img
```

According to Albumentations's [docs](https://albumentations.ai/docs/examples/pytorch_classification/), you can make a composition of Transforms and use it within PyTorch dataset.

```py
import albumentations as A
from albumentations.pytorch import ToTensorV2

train_transform = A.Compose(
    [
        A.SmallestMaxSize(max_size=160),
        A.ShiftScaleRotate(shift_limit=0.05, scale_limit=0.05, rotate_limit=15, p=0.5),
        A.RandomCrop(height=128, width=128),
        A.RGBShift(r_shift_limit=15, g_shift_limit=15, b_shift_limit=15, p=0.5),
        A.RandomBrightnessContrast(p=0.5),
        A.Normalize(mean=(0.485, 0.456, 0.406), std=(0.229, 0.224, 0.225)),
        ToTensorV2(),
    ]
)
train_dataset = CatsVsDogsDataset(images_filepaths=train_images_filepaths, transform=train_transform)
```

[image]

But I am not really sure that normalizing mask image is right way or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'm sorry I probably wasn't clear enough, that's my bad.
Your former solution is what I tried, that doesn't work (mask doesn't get normalized) writing it additionally in dataloader works, the or doesn't either, you may edit and I'll accept

Comment: Hi, I think I understood now, one way is stacking the mask image and make three-channel image then apply `A.Normalize(mean, std)` . I am really not sure about it.

Comment: @yakho no I have an image and a mask so I transform once the image and once the mask, you had an earlier suggestion to just use normalize in the dataset. that's what I did after transforms I added image = A.normalize(image), mask = A.Normalize(mask)
before I did train_transforms(image = image, mask = mask) but according to the documentation masks aren't normalized

Comment: see https://albumentations.ai/docs/examples/example_kaggle_salt/ also

Comment: I am wondering how it may affect to the mask image if you just normalize the image. As I far as I know normalization does not make any change to the shape of image, so why we need to normalize the mask as well? Sorry If I misunderstand you.

Comment: @yakho didn't need to originally. It just happend to be pretrained that way.